# A simple yet tricky binomial question

Tags: binomial-theorem

> What are the number of dissimilar terms in the expansion of $(x+\frac{1}{x}+x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})^{15}$?

I know how to solve this kind of problem.

First I would arrange the term into a binomial expression. The expansion will have $(n+1)$ dissimilar terms.

But how can I arrange it into a binomial expression?

Comment: I don't understand your method.  What's the highest degree term?  What's the lowest?  Do all the intermediate terms have non-zero coefficients?

Comment: For example, let us find the number of dissimilar terms in $(1-3x+3x^2-x^3)^{33}$. It is equal to $((1-x)^{3})^{33}$=$(1-x)^{99}$. Therefore it has $99+1=100$ terms. Here, in my question, I want to know how to arrange it into binomial expression.

Comment: But not everything has such a simple form.

Comment: @Iulu Yes, it is not necessary that all the intermediate terms have non-zero coefficients. It seems that this technique won't work.

Comment: Which intermediate coefficient do you believe has a zero coefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$x+\dfrac{1}{x} = t \Rightarrow x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2} = t^2 - 2$$

$$\therefore \Big(x+\dfrac{1}{x}+x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\Big)^{15} = (t^2+t-2)^{15} $$

Now consider @lulu's precious advice : "What's the highest degree term? What's the lowest? Do all the intermediate terms have non-zero coefficients?"

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would proceed with the question:

$(x+\frac{1}{x}+x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})^{15}$ = $(\frac{1+x+x^3+x^4}{x^2})^{15}$
= $(\frac{1}{x^30})(1+x+x^3+x^4)^{15}$
= $(\frac{1}{x^30})$(1+.......+x^60)

That expression has 61 different powers. So the answer should be 61. Hope it helps!

Comment: are you sure there are $61$? You can get, for example $x^{-15}$ in at least 2 ways. 5*3, and $15*1.$

Comment: Yeah, I think so. Taking the example which you have given, we can club the terms having power $x^{-15}$. I'm not saying that we'll get 61 terms, all I am saying is that we'll have 61 different powers after clubbing the terms.